# What the meaning of <fieldsets> in config.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, customer-attribute

Here is my code.

```
<global>
    <fieldsets>
        <customer_account>
          <customeattribute>
            <create>1</create>
            <update>1</update>
            <name>1</name>
          </customattribute>
        </customer_account>
    </fieldsets>
</global>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `<fieldsets>` tag is basically used to define attributes that will be copied from one place to another. For example, while converting quote object to order object, the attributes that needs to move to order is listed below like,

```
<sales_convert_quote>
                <remote_ip>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </remote_ip>
                <x_forwarded_for>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </x_forwarded_for>
                <customer_id>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </customer_id>
                <customer_email>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </customer_email>
                <customer_prefix>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </customer_prefix>
                <customer_firstname>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </customer_firstname>
                <customer_middlename>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </customer_middlename>
                <customer_lastname>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </customer_lastname>
               <...........>
</sales_convert_quote>
```

The above code has been taken from the file 
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml

Hope this helps.
Thanks.

Comment: Following code syntax is different. <customeattribute>
            <create>1</create>
            <update>1</update>
            <name>1</name>
          </customattribute> while you mentioned the * between  <remote_ip>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </remote_ip> So I get confused.

Comment: Yes, this syntax that you have mentioned is for adding new customer attributes. Here your have added one attribute with the name "customattribute"

Answer (score 0):

`<fieldsets>` tag is generally used to define `which fields (attributes) are to be copied to where while converting objects to object,`